# What's the IP address of my SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, dns

I'm actually learning about SharePoint Server so I was following a course on LinkedIn Learning and the instructor said that I will need the IP address of the SharePoint Server to configure the DNS for web applications, except that we don't have the same thing inside the DNS Manager, I don't know if it's normal or not.

His DNS Manager
[image]

My DNS Manager
[image]

The Host "teams" is the one I need to give the same IP as my SharePoint Server, I tried using the Windows Server IP but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In the command prompt on your SharePoint Server, type "ipconfig /all" to reveal all the IPv4 addresses available on the server. If more than one, you need to look in the IIS manager as to which IP is bound to the SharePoint Application

Comment: There's only one IP adresse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal since you are building a new environment.

You only need to get the IP address on the **domain controller** by running `IPCONFIG` in *command prompt (cmd)*, and then set it as the DNS server address under IPv4 via *Network and Sharing Center*.

You will not be able to get all IP addresses of all servers using `ipconfig /all` until you finish connecting the servers.

Here is one related post of discussion for your reference:
[Change server ip address SharePoint 2013.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7e8d1271-de25-446b-b9c4-9a403c35ecf6/change-server-ip-address-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadminprevious)